# Using the results of one query as a subarray in the results of another

Tags: php, mysql

I am almost sure I'm phrasing this incorrectly however what I'm trying to do is combine the results of two joined tables but without duplicates.

I have two tables, `events` and `going`. What I'm trying to do is have a query that gets the row from `events`, then as a sub array, list all the rows from `going` that have the same `EventID`. Something like:

```
 "1":[
   {
   EventID: '1'
   EventName: 'test'
   Going: {
     UserID:'testname'
     UserID:'testname2'
     }
   }
 ]
```

Or possibly having all the usernames on one line such as `UserID: 'testname', 'testname2'`

I'm using this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM events AS ev INNER JOIN going AS go ON ev.EventID = go.EventID WHERE ev.EventID = $eventID"
```

And I'm instead getting results like:

```
"1":[
   {
   EventID: '1'
   EventName: 'test'
   UserID:'testname'
   }
   {
   EventID: '1'
   EventName: 'test'
   UserID:'testname2'
   }
]
```

Is there any way to remove all that duplicate data and instead just group it in a sub array?

Please excuse any terrible coding/formatting, I'm a complete SQL noob but I can't seem to find how to do this if it's even possible. Hopefully I'm communicating what I'm trying to do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think it cannot be done that way. but it can be done this way Going : testname, testname2 if you only use sql

Comment: That would also work, would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```sql
SELECT e.EventID, e.EventName, GROUP_CONCAT(g.UserID) Going
  FROM events AS e INNER JOIN going AS g
    ON e.EventID = g.EventID 
 WHERE e.EventID = ?
 GROUP BY e.EventID, e.EventName
```

Output:

```
| EVENTID | EVENTNAME |              GOING |
|---------|-----------|--------------------|
|       1 |      test | testname2,testname |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/903fb/2)** demo

And then `explode()` `going` column while you're iterating over the resultset and producing your JSON.

---

On a side note: **stop** using query string interpolation. Instead learn and make use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`, something like this:

```
SELECT ev.EventID, ev.EventName, GROUP_CONCAT(go.UserID) AS UserIDs
FROM events AS ev INNER JOIN going AS go ON ev.EventID = go.EventID
WHERE ev.EventID = $eventID
GROUP BY ev.EventID, ev.EventName
```

See working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa4875/11

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with one query. You need to grab the eventId and its related data from the events table. Then, query your going table with the eventId and through your programming logic, create your required array/json.